# Open sets in $S_\Omega$ (minimal uncountable well ordered set) with the order topology.

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, well-orders

$X$ is a well ordered set. $S_\Omega= \{ x:x\in X\text{ and } x<\Omega\}$ such that it is the minimal uncountable well ordered set. The section $S_\Omega$ of $X$ is uncountable and any other section of $X$ is countable (a section is $S_\alpha=\{ x:x\in X\text{ and } x<\alpha\}$).

I'm having trouble with open sets with the order topology. I've read that if $x$ has no predecessor then $\{x\}$ is not open, and if $x$ has a predecessor then $\{x\}$ is open. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ has predecessor $y$ then $\{x\}=\{z\mid z<x+1\}\cap\{z\mid y<z\}$ or more shortly $\{x\}=(y,x+1)$ which is an open set according to the order topology.

If $x$ has no predecessor then for every $y<x$ the set $(y,x+1)$ contains $y+1<x$ so that $\{x\}\neq(y,x+1)$.

---

**Edit**:

One exception though: if $x$ is smallest element of $X$ then it has no predecessor but $\{x\}$ is open.

Comment: I catched the first part, but if $x$ has no predecessor, why you can take $y<x$? That is what confuses me. I know it is correct, but my intuition goes th other way round.

Comment: Oh, since $x$ has no predecessor, for every $y<x$, there exist $y+1$ such that $y<y+1<x$ and therefore the same open set $(y,x+1)$ we had before would have more elements than $\{x\}$ and then we can't right singleton $x$ as an interval. Is it ok?

Comment: There is an exception (which I overlooked). If $x$ is smallest element of $X$ then it has no predecessor, but nevertheless $\{x\}$ is open. What you state in your comment is correct. $y<x$ implies that $y+1<x$ if $x$ has no predecessor.

Comment: Yes, since it is well ordered, the $\{\min S_\Omega\}=[\min S_\Omega,\zeta)$ with $\zeta$ the immediate sucessor of $\min S_\Omega$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Right, thank you very much! :)

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad to help.